# UIScrollView contentOffset resets when tapped

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which resets its `contentOffset` anytime the view is tapped.

This is demonstrated here: https://gyazo.com/c8fb5c0fa5b6d53acf45c809dcb5b251

**What I've tried**:

1. Disabling keyboard dismissal
2. Checking for `isDragging` on `scrollViewDidScroll` and resetting the content offset if it was false. This resulted in jumpy behavior.
3. Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003775/uiscrollviews-contentoffset-being-reset-when-clicking-anywhere), it did not help.

You can test it yourself here: https://github.com/willbishop/scrollviewwizardry

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off paging if that is not the intended result you're looking for:

`scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false`

If paging *is* something you're looking to use:

Paging is meant for snapping between multiple views in a ScrollView, usually where each subview is the size of the ScrollView's bounds. Since you've enabled paging with vertical scrolling, and your ScrollView content height is less than two "pages" height, unexpected results from paging are occurring.

For your situation, if you set each view in your ScrollView equal to the ScrollView's height, and your ScrollView contentSize height is equal to its subview's combined height, then paging works properly and the content offset doesn't reset when tapped:

```
scrollView.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
subView1.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
subView2.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
scrollView.contentSize.height = subView1.frame.height + subView2.frame.height
```

It will snap between showing your two views when the ScrollView stops being scrolled. You could also have your "peekAmount" where the second view shows at the bottom while still scrolled to the top "page", as long as the height of your ScrollView contentSize is equal to twice the ScrollView bounds height (i.e. two pages).